# Error en Jupyter, red bayesiana funciona pero marca un error

Tags: python, jupyter, anaconda3

estaba practicando con este código y si me devuelve la respuesta pero me sale en color rojo esto:

```
<ipython-input-10-347a2c3f7518>:28: FutureWarning: In v4.0, pm.sample will return an `arviz.InferenceData` object instead of a `MultiTrace` by default. You can pass return_inferencedata=True or return_inferencedata=False to be safe and silence this warning.
  trace = pm.sample(20000,
Multiprocess sampling (4 chains in 4 jobs)
BinaryGibbsMetropolis: [lluvia, rociador]
```

Después carga una barra del 1 al 100 y sale lo siguiente:

```
Sampling 4 chains for 5_000 tune and 20_000 draw iterations (20_000 + 80_000 draws total) took 53 seconds.
The number of effective samples is smaller than 10% for some parameters.
```

Este es mi código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import seaborn as sns
import pymc3 as pm

# Problema de la hierba mojada
# https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_bayesiana#Ejemplo

niter = 10000  # 10000
tune = 5000  # 5000

modelo = pm.Model()

with modelo:
    tv = [1]
    lluvia = pm.Bernoulli('lluvia', 0.2, shape=1, testval=tv)
    rociador_p = pm.Deterministic('rociador_p', 
                                  pm.math.switch(lluvia, 0.01, 0.40))
    rociador = pm.Bernoulli('rociador', rociador_p, shape=1, testval=tv)
    hierba_mojada_p = pm.Deterministic('hierba_mojada_p', 
                pm.math.switch(lluvia, pm.math.switch(rociador, 0.99, 0.80),
                               pm.math.switch(rociador, 0.90, 0.0)))
    hierba_mojada = pm.Bernoulli('hierba_mojada', hierba_mojada_p,
                             observed=np.array([1]), shape=1)

    trace = pm.sample(20000, 
                      step=[pm.BinaryGibbsMetropolis([lluvia, rociador])], 
                      tune=tune, random_seed=124)

# pm.traceplot(trace)

dictionary = {
              'lluvia': [1 if ii[0] else 0 for ii in trace['lluvia'].tolist() ],
              'rociador': [1 if ii[0] else 0 for ii in trace['rociador'].tolist() ],
              'rociador_p': [ii[0] for ii in trace['rociador_p'].tolist()],
              'hierba_mojada_p': [ii[0] for ii in trace['hierba_mojada_p'].tolist()],
              }
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)

p_lluvia = df[(df['lluvia'] == 1)].shape[0] / df.shape[0]
print("\nProbabilidad de que la hierba este mojada por la lluvia: {0}"
      .format(p_lluvia))

p_rociador = df[(df['rociador'] == 1)].shape[0] / df.shape[0]
print("Probabilidad de que la hierba este mojada por el rociador: {0}"
      .format(p_rociador))
```

Comment: no es un error, es una advertencia, diciendo que en futuras versiones puede cambiar la forma en que te retorna un dato.

Comment: Ahh ya, con razón si me devuelve el resultado, muchas gracias!

Comment: de nada ^_^, como recomendación haz caso a la advertencia

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación :D